# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer los datos de este array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy trayendo datos desde una consulta `SQL` mediante `PHP`, el problema es que ahora lo hago mediante un ciclo `For`, esto debido a que deseo realizar 4 consultas distintas y traer sus datos para usarlos, pero cuando quiero recorrer el arreglo mediante `foreach()` obtengo la `string array` como resultado y no los valores numéricos almacenados en ella.

La consulta la realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
for ($semanaActual; $semanaActual < $semanaLimite; $semanaActual++) {
            $sem1 = $sistema[0]["$semanaActual.1"];
            $sem2 = $sistema[0]["$semanaActual.2"];

            $consulta = $conexion->prepare("
                SELECT sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20 
                FROM $bandera 
                WHERE idm = $idMesero 
                AND fechavta BETWEEN '$sem1' AND '$sem2'
                ");
            $consulta->execute();
            $respuestas = $consulta->fetchAll();

    //Valores: $semanaActual = 23, $semanaLimite = 27, lo cual ejecuta el ciclo 4 veces

}
```

Y desde la vista `HTML`, sin éxito he intentado traer los datos así:

```
foreach ($respuestas as $respuesta) {
    echo $respuesta[0] . ', ' . $respuesta[1] . ', ' . $respuesta[2] . ', ' . $respuesta[3];
}
```

Al realizar un `print_r()` del `array $respuestas`, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20] => 650
            [0] => 650
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20] => 180
            [0] => 180
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20] => 390
            [0] => 390
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20] => 140
            [0] => 140
        )

)
```

Que es donde considero puede estar la respuesta, o guardar los datos de otra manera, ya que actualmente uso `fetchAll()`.

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: `foreach ($respuestas as $respuesta) {
    echo $respuesta[0][0] ;
}` probaste así?

Comment: @CesarRomero ya lo intente de esa manera, pero no funciona, me arroja un entero 1

Answer (score 0):

lo primero, te diria que cambiaras la consulta. Si te das cuenta, el listado de arrays que te devuelve tiene, cada item, una clave `0` y una clave con el nombre de la operacion del sql. En su lugar, te recomiendo cambiarlo por:

```
SELECT sum(mezcla) * 10 + sum(botella) * 30 + sum(shot) * 20 AS suma 
FROM $bandera 
WHERE idm = $idMesero 
      AND fechavta BETWEEN '$sem1' AND '$sem2'
```

de esta manera, el fechAll() debera asignarte como nombre de clave el texto `suma`, y el array sera del tipo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suma] => 650
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [suma] => 180
        )

...
```

Una vez hecho esto, acceder al array se convierte en esto:

```
foreach ($respuestas as $respuesta) {
    echo $respuesta['suma'];
}
```